# UITableView empty, even after calling reloadData

Tags: iphone

Kind of following this tutorial here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/

I use the fetch records method in my AppNameDelegate.m file. I then call reload on my tableview. Unlike the linked tutorial, I am not using a UITableViewController. Instead, I have added a table view to the NavigationController, and connected it to the IBOutlet variable called contactsTable.

Here's my code for calling and loading the data:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

    [self.window addSubview:[self.navigationController view]];
    [self fetchRecords];
    [self.contactsTable reloadData];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

The header file:

```
//
//  SimpleContactsAppDelegate.h
//  SimpleContacts
//
//  Created by Aaron McLeod on 11-05-28.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface SimpleContactsAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;    
    UIWindow *window;  
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    // view for adding new contacts
    UIViewController *newContactView;
    UIButton *addButton;

    // controls for the addContactView
    UIButton *saveContactButton;
    UITextField *nameField;
    UITextField *emailField;
    UITextField *phoneField;

    UITableView *contactsTable;
    NSMutableArray *contactArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;  
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;  
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *addButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *contactsTable;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *contactArray;

// controller and fields for the form
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *newContactView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *emailField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *phoneField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *saveContactButton;


- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
- (IBAction) saveContact;
- (IBAction) switchToAddContactView;
- (void)fetchRecords;
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

@end
```

You can find my project source code here as well: https://github.com/agmcleod/SimpleContacts/tree/parttwo In case i left out code you might need. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not even sure why it's so low. 11/13 of my questions all have accepted answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing `reloadData` does is tell the `UITableView` to ask its data source for new data. This means it'll call `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` etc. Have you set up this relationship correctly?

In your case, your `SimpleContactsAppDelegate` instance should be the `dataSource` of your table view (do the connection in Interface Builder).

Consider using `NSFetchedResultsController` when using Core Data and UITableViews. This allows you to not load all the objects into memory at once, etc. Xcode's sample code provides a good starting point for this (I think it's the Navigation Controller based app with Core Data template).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll definitely check that out.

Comment: That did the trick. Just had to point it as the data source. I already had defined the methods there. Thank you.